# Block property ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, error-handling, block, flashdevelop

I don't know why I'm getting this error in AS3, "Access of undefined property Block.".

I was following a tutorial and copied the code as it is,

```
function mainLoop (e:Event) {
   for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
   if (getChildAt(i) is Block)
   {
      var bb = getChildAt(i) as Block;
      if (bb.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY))
      {
      trace("hit"); 
      }
   }
   }    
}
```

Maybe a missing import? Although FlashDevelop didn't automatically add as it does sometimes so I'm a bit clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have class definition for `Block`. It could be exported as part of .swc library or defined in code. Without definition of `Block` class of cause you will have errors.

Also you could improve your main loop, you shouldn't perform several times same lookup with `getChildAt` and operations `is` and `as` also could be optimised:

```
function mainLoop(e:Event) {
    var block:Block, len:int = numChildren, i:int;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        block = getChildAt(i) as Block;
        if (block != null) {
            if (block.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                trace("hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was following a tutorial. I read the code and picked up some part of it, sometimes I just don't understand. I didn't understand what a class definition is although I read some stuff about classes and even made a class on my own (so I'm not completely clueless on classes). I started on as3 a few days ago, hope you understand (shouldn't be here asking for code pieces :P) - So, class definition for block? Like "public class Block extends ..."?

Comment: Yes, `public class Block extends Sprite`

Comment: If I change Block to Example, which is the name of the main class, it doesn't give any errors but it doesn't trace anything either.

Comment: I already had the class definition, "public class Example extends Sprite". I thought 'block' was a property that an object could have, and so, the code was gonna go through stuff on stage to check if they were block, and if so do something about it, and in the case above it outputs "hit!" to the screen.

The goal here is to add collision! So it should check with elements on stage if they collide. What is block exactly then in that code?

Comment: In this code, `block` is an instance of class `Block`.